# SignalR does not connect on release mode

Tags: flutter, signalr

I have an application that uses SignalR for push notifications.

here is my code

```
final SignalR client = SignalR(
  "URL",
  "Notification",
  headers: <String, String>{"Authorization": "Admin"},
  hubMethods: <String>["SendTransactionDataJson"],
  statusChangeCallback: print,
  hubCallback: (final String methodName, final String message) {
    final MessageDataBase dataBase = MessageDataBase.fromJson(getString(AppConstants.messages) ?? "{}");
    if (MessageResponse.fromJson(message).userStatusList!.isNotEmpty) {
      dataBase.messages.add(MessageResponse.fromJson(message));
      dataBase.messages.toSet();
      setData(AppConstants.messages, dataBase.toJson());
      showNotification();
    }
    Core.messageDataBase = dataBase;
  },
);
```

my app is working perfectly on debug mode. but it does not connect to server on release mode.

I use `signalr_flutter` package.
I also added Internet permission on manifest too, but nothing changed.